# How to find ALL optimal local alignments using Smith-Waterman?

Tags: bioinformatics, text-alignment

If I got this right then it is possible that there is more than one max value in the local alignment matrix. So in order to get all optimal local alignments, instead of only one, I would have to find the location of all these maximum values in the matrix and trace each of them back individually, right?

Example:

```
XGTCXXGTCX 
 |||
AGTCA

XGTCXXGTCX 
      |||
     AGTCA
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as ALL optimal alignments.  There should only be one optimal alignment.  I guess there could be multiple paths for the same alignment but they would have the same overall score and it doesn't look like that's the kind of question you are asking.

What your diagram in your post shows is multiple (primer?) hits.  In such a case, what I do is I run smith-waterman once, get the optimal alignment.  Then I generate a new alignment where the subject sequence has been trimmed to only include the downstream sequence.  The advantage to this way is I don't have to modify any S-W code or have to dig in the internals of 3rd party code.

So it would look like this:

Alignment 1

```
XGTCXXGTCX 
 |||
AGTCA
```

Delete upstream subject sequence:

```
XGTCXXGTCX => XGTCX
```

Alignment 2

```
 XGTCX 
  |||
 AGTCA
```

The only tricky part is you have to keep track of how many bases have been deleted from the alignment so you can correctly adjust the match coordinates.

Comment: `There is no such thing as ALL optimal alignments. There should only be one optimal alignment.` How do you come to that conclusion? Sounds wrong to me.

Comment: From a S-W perspective there is only 1 optimal alignment.  If multiple alignments have the same best score, then only 1 is chosen (which one is chosen is implementation specific) so there can only be one picked alignment.

Comment: So you are basically saying, that a SW-Alignment per definition only outputs one aligment? Hmm, then I guess OP is asking for a modification of the SW - algorithm that outputs all optimal local alignments.

Comment: Yes S-W will only ever output 1 alignment.  the OP wants to know how to get all the other just as good local alignments which is why I suggested re-aligning with a substring instead of having to modify any S-W code

Comment: And why not simply rewrite the traceback to start at all maximums in the dynamic programming matrix? To be honest, I was very surprised by your answer, because adapting the traceback seems so straight forward and also OP suggested  that in his question.

Comment: Because then it wouldn't be S-W. But you are right, if you have access to the traceback matrix you could search for other best hits.

Comment: @dkatzel, this is not true.  It is very possible that SW could have multiple alignments with the same score.  In fact, there are SW implementations that do report all of the optimal alignments.  The biopython implementation: https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Align.PairwiseAligner-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is pretty old nowadays but since I found that, other People might also find this while looking for help and in my opinion, the correct answer has not been given, yet. So:
Clearly, there can be MULTIPLE optimal local alignments. You've just shown an example of such. Yet, there is EXACTLY ONE optimal local alignment SCORE. Looking at the original paper that presented the SmithWaterman-Algorithm, Smith and Waterman already indicate how to find the second best alignment, third best alignment...

here's a Reprint to read that stuff (for your Problem, check page 196):
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/40c5/441aad96b366996e6af163ca9473a19bb9ad.pdf

So (in contrast to other answers on here), the SmithWaterman-Algorithm also gives second best local alignments and so on.
Just check for the second best score within your Scoringmatrix (in your case there'll be several entries with the same best score), that is not associated with your best local alignment, do the usual backtracking and you solved your Problem. :)